# Why does my chart ignore a VBA command, and how to prevent it?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

95% of the time the code I'm using will work fine, producing some gauge charts by using a doughnut-pie chart combo.  One requirement in this is that the Doughnut portion be plotted on the secondary axis, or there will be a failure when it reaches certain series collection points.  I have a command that explicitly addresses this, but the other 5% of the time it is randomly ignored and causes everything to come to screeching halt.  I've tried some error checking to force it to reapply the secondary AxisGroup setting, but that is likewise ignored.

This seems to occur only after running the macro several times on the same worksheet.  Closing Excel and running it again seems to fix it, but I'd rather know what the cause is and fix it to prevent any headaches.

```
Sub ChartSetup(cht As Chart, objChart As ChartObject, shpChart As Shape, rngFormula As Range)
    Dim lStock As Long, lAttempt As Long
    Dim dTitleWidth As Double, dTitleHeight As Double
    Dim dChartWidth As Double, dChartHeight As Double
    Dim dTitleLeft As Double, dTitleTop As Double
    
    dChartWidth = 210: dChartHeight = 210
    lAttempt = 0
    
    On Error GoTo RetryAxis
    
    With shpChart
        .Height = dChartWidth
        .Width = dChartHeight
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        With .Chart
            .HasTitle = True
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay)
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)

                With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
RetryAxis:
                    .ChartType = xlDoughnut
                    ' AxisGroup = 2 is sometimes ignored.  Why?
                    .AxisGroup = 2
                    lAttempt = lAttempt + 1
                    
                    If lAttempt > 5 Then GoTo ExitThis
                    
                    shpChart.Chart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 70
                    shpChart.Chart.ChartGroups(1).FirstSliceAngle = 270
                    
                    With .Points(1).Format.Fill
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(139, 0, 0)
                        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
                        .GradientStops(2).Color.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)
                        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 0, 0), 0.15
                        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 165, 0), 0.3
                        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 255, 0), 0.5
                        .GradientStops.Insert RGB(144, 238, 144), 0.75
                    End With
                    
                    .Points(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    
                    ' Fails here if not on secondary axis.
                    .Points(4).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
                    .Points(4).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                    
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo RetryAxis
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End With
  
' More code below
```

Comment: To help you need post all the code, but something wrong happens here: The: "On Error GoTo RetryAxis" points you to a point where "With .FullSeriesCollection(1)" may not have been executed but the code assumes it is. You also have a loop that you control with "Attempt" which looks like you are playing dice because between "If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo RetryAxis" and the point "RetryAxis" nothing changes except "Attempt".

Comment: You use "On Error Goto", but you say VBA "ignores" the command - does it even raise an error when it does that?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, it raises one.  I can't recall the number offhand, but will post it when it happens next.